# How to create rows of non-duplicating strings from a list?

Tags: python, random

I want to create a `16X4` data frame with these coordinates as strings: `"(.1,.1)","(-.1,-.1)","(-.1,.1)","(.1,-.1)"`. But, I do want not there to be duplicates.

To put it another way, the script would output a `16X4` matrix/dataframe like this:

```
"(.1,.1)","(-.1,-.1)","(-.1,.1)","(.1,-.1)"
"(-.1,.1)","(-.1,-.1)","(.1,.1)","(.1,-.1)"
"(-.1,-.1)","(.1,.1)","(-.1,.1)","(.1,-.1)" ...
```

In this way, I would get all the possible combinations of these four coordinates with no column duplicates.

I have been trying to brainstorm solutions. I know I can put them in an array and use `random.choice()` to randomly sample. But, I am not sure how to form this code in such a way where there will be no column duplicates and that patterns wont repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not strings.  They are tuples of floating point values.  You're confusing things by using the wrong terminology.

```
import itertools
src = [(.1,.1),(-.1,-.1),(-.1,.1),(.1,-.1)]

for opt in itertools.permutations(src):
    print(opt)
```

If you really need the permutations in random order, then take the result into a list and shuffle:

```
import random
import itertools

src = [(.1,.1),(-.1,-.1),(-.1,.1),(.1,-.1)]
def makethem():
    vals = list(itertools.permutations(src))
    random.shuffle(vals)
    return vals[:16]
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP realized there are 24 permutations, not 16...

Comment: Yeah, not sure what they want. They call it "all the possible combinations", so they got *something* wrong.